# Не работает сравнение строк из EditText с образцами строк по нажатию кнопки

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Делаю приложение тест. На дисплее отображаются 3 фразы которые нужно продолжить. У каждой фразы свой edit text. Если пользователь введет правильный ответ, то после нажатия на кнопку, edit text выделяется зеленым, если нет, то красным. Если все edit text заполнены правильно (становятся зелеными), то intent перебрасывает на новое активити.

Проблема в том, что что-то у меня не так с условием (if), выделяется первое поле все время красным, остальные вообще не выделяются, так же думаю, как их перечислить в условии, чтобы intent перебросил их на новое активити?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText et_one_one, et_one_two, et_one_three;
    Button buttonCheck;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /** текстовые поля, в которые пользователь вводит значения*/
        et_one_one = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_one_one);
        et_one_two = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_one_two);
        et_one_three = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_one_three);

        /** получаем эти значения и сохраняем в переменных*/
        String t1 = et_one_one.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
        String t2 = et_one_two.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
        String t3 =  et_one_three.getText().toString().toLowerCase();

        buttonCheck = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCheck);

        buttonCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                /** при клике сравниваем значения с образцами*/
                boolean allAnswersCorrect = true;

                if (t1.equals("maserati")){
                    et_one_one.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                }
                else {
                    allAnswersCorrect = false;
                    et_one_one.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                }

                if (t2.equals("mercedes")){
                    et_one_two.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                }
                else{
                    allAnswersCorrect = false;
                    et_one_two.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                }

                if (t3.equals("bmw")){
                    et_one_three.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                }
                else{
                    allAnswersCorrect = false;
                    et_one_three.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                }
                if(allAnswersCorrect) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: вам дали аж целых 2 правильных ответа, Виталий Обидейко и Eugene Krivenja.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, до редактирования он проблему абсолютно не решал, после редактирования - он копирует ответ Виталий Обидейко.

Comment: Не согласен с причиной закрытия. Ошибка не только в опечатке, а прежде всего в том, когда получаются значения, с которыми происходит сравнение. Плюс в коде присутствует копипаста, которую необходимо рефакторить. Всё это вполне воспроизводимо и встречается часто.

Comment: @metalurgus придержите такой тон для кого-нибудь другого, а со мной общайтесь уважительно, даже если не согласны. В данном случае вы ошиблись в том, что закрыли вопрос по неверной причине. Почитайте формулировку: разве проблема не воспроизводится? Разве дело только в опечатке? Разве отсутствует mcve?

Comment: @NickVolynkin в общем то ваш ответ скорее для [этого вопроса](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/443259/177345), которому требуется только изменить заголовок с невероятно общего на более приближенный к конкретной решаемой проблеме. С этим вопросом, к сожалению, все так плохо, что его уже не исправить для возможности переиспользования (хотя бы в силу самой формулировки и прочих полученных ответов). Тут классическая проблема XY

Comment: @pavlofff хм, действительно. Я не видел того вопроса. Но там акцент именно на то, как работать с набором строковых полей неопределенного количества. Пожалуй, мой ответ готовит почву для решения того вопроса, но не отвечает на него.

Comment: @pavlofff согласен, что вопрос переиспользовать сложно. Попробовал все-таки улучшить ситуацию правкой, акцентируя внимание на логике и ее нарушениях.

Comment: @NickVolynkin [про этот вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/443259/177345) Думаю это автор сгоряча про сотню фраз, особенно после [этого](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/443423/177345). Думаю, "сотня" можно заменить на "несколько" и хоть один вопрос из серии этого автора может быть полезным другим. Я предлагаю ваш ответ перенсти туда.

Comment: @pavlofff ага, я уже на это [намекал](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/443423/#comment467304_443428). Предложу автору переформулировать тот вопрос с новым кодом. Тогда действительно получится полезный вопрос.

Comment: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1074/178988

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Ошибка в логике, которая вызвала вопрос

Проверяемое значение строки нужно получать при клике, а не при создании, как верно [указал Виталий Обидейко](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/443348/181472). После копипасты не исправили имена переменных, что [заметил Eugene Krivenja](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/443196/181472).

#### Ошибки архитектуры и стиля

Так называемый, "технический долг". Обязательно спровоцирует дальнейшие ошибки и запутывание кода.

**Выделение методов и разделение ответственности**

Тут буквально напрашивается рефакторинг под названием выделение метода. Теперь, если вы захотите поменять цвета или иным образом обрабатывать верные и неверные значения, вам нужно будет это делать в одном месте.

Обратите внимание, что на самом деле выполняются три задачи: проверка валидности, изменение отображения, управление логикой всего этого. Таким образом, нам нужны три метода.

**Управление доступом**

Если к переменным класса `EditText` не нужно обращаться из других классов этого же пакета, то пакетный доступ (без модификатора) следует изменить на приватный (`private`). Разрешайте только то, что явно хотите разрешить. Аналогично с `buttonCheck`.

Если переменные классов `EditText` & `Button` используются только в одном методе этого класса, то желательно переместить их объявление. Пускай они существуют только в том пространстве имен, в котором нужны. Это убережет ваш код от случайного присвоения одному из `EditText` нового значения, после которого переключение цветов сломается.

**Прочий рефакторинг**

Константы хранить в коде нехорошо. Константы должны быть доступны через класс ресурсов. Таким образом вы разделяете данные и их обработку. Поэтому строковые константы мы заменяем обращениями к значению в `R` (а там их теперь нужно добавить в XML со строками).

Параметры во всех новых методах объявляем `final`. Это тема отдельного вопроса. Просто так лучше.

Если переменные `et_one_four`, `et_one_five` не используются, то не нужно их и объявлять. Это запутывает код. Если такие поля есть и проверяются, то, наоборот, нужно включить их обработку в код.

**Стиль кода**

Именование переменных через `_` не принято в Java, а принят `camelCase`, когда слова записываются подряд, первое с маленькой буквы, следующие с большой. Нельзя утверждать, что этот стандарт однозначно улучшает или ухудшает читаемость, но ему нужно следовать, если не хотите, чтобы коллеги нервно дергали глазом при виде вашего кода. =)

**Собственно, итоговый код**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

/** Определяет валидность значения.
Ничего не знает о том, как используется его результат*/
private boolean isValid(final EditText source, final String expected) {
String actual = source.getText().toString();
return expected.equals(actual);
}

/** Управляет отображением валидности в интерфейсе.
Ничего не знает о том, где и как проверяется валидность */
private void toggleColor(final EditText source, final boolean isValid) { 
    int backgroundColor = (isValid)? Color.GREEN : Color.RED;
    source.setBackgroundcolor(backgroundColor);
}

/** управляет логикой, не знает о том, как она реализована в интерфейсе */
private void checkValidity(final EditText source, final String expected) { 
    boolean valid = isValid(source, expected);
    toggleColor(source, valid); 
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // эти значения вы передаете в экземпляр создаваемого анонимного класса, они обязаны быть final
    final EditText  missingText11 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.missingText11);
    final EditText  missingText12 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.missingText12);
    final EditText  missingText13 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.missingText13);

    Button buttonCheck = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCheck)

    buttonCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // видно, что мы сравниваем текстовые поля именно с теми значениями, с которыми и задумывали
            checkValidity(missingText11, R.id.validText11);
            checkValidity(missingText12, R.id.validText12);
            checkValidity(missingText13, R.id.validText13);

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Nick, да вы волшебник! Я 2 дня голову ломал, как архитектуру оптимизировать, а вы и на этот вопрос здесь ответили!)) Спасибо, ОГРОМНОЕ!

Comment: @НиколайБойко об этом уже [нужно задавать новый вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=android+android-edittext+intent). Опубликуйте  в нем тот код, которым вы сейчас пытаетесь добавить `Intent`, опишите точным образом логику, которую вы пытаетесь реализовать, желаемый и фактический результаты. Если вы всё сделаете верно, новый вопрос не закроют и на него наверняка будет дан ответ.

Comment: Готово: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/443423/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9

Answer (score 3):

Неправильно работаете с EditText. Так как очевидно, что вы получаете строки из EditText'ов во время создания активити, а в итоге действия пользователя не учитываются. Поэтому, нужно получать данные из EditText'ов в OnClick. Иначе всегда все будет красное!

```
buttonCheck = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCheck);

buttonCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final String t1 = et_one_one.getText().toString();
        final String t2 = et_one_two.getText().toString();
        final String t3 =  et_one_three.getText().toString();
        if (t1.equals("maserati")){
            et_one_one.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
        else {
            et_one_one.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
        if (t2.equals("mercedes")){
            et_one_one.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
        else{
            et_one_one.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
        if (t3.equals("bmw")){
            et_one_one.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
        else{
            et_one_one.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Я немного переработал ваши изменения, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/443391/181472

Comment: Увидел. Думаю, что основная проблема была именно в этом. Но ваш ответ более развернутый. :)

Comment: Виталий, тут оказались еще связанные вопросы. Если разбираетесь в андроиде, может там дадите развернутое решение. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/443259/%D0%90%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0?lq=1

Answer (score 2):

У Вас в `onClick` везде `et_one_one`, copy-paste вредная привычка :)
Должно быть

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (t1.equals("maserati")){
        et_one_one.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    } else {
        et_one_one.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
    if (t2.equals("mercedes")){
        et_one_two.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    } else{
        et_one_two.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
    if (t3.equals("bmw")){
        et_one_three.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    } else{
        et_one_three.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, за внимательность!)

Comment: Хорошо, что заметили, но дублирование кода все равно осталось.