# Переход на другую активити при совпадении нескольких условий

Tags: java, android, android-intent

По логике данный код должен сравнивать ответы, введеные в `EditText`, с ответами из условия и выделять поля: при правильном ответе - зеленым, при не правильном -красным. Если все ответы верны, переходить на новое активити. Если нет, то нет.

Данный код переход на новое активити вне зависимости, верные ли ответы. Как исправить его, не нарушив архитектуры?

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private boolean isValid(final EditText source, final String expected) {
        String actual = source.getText().toString();
        return expected.equals(actual);
    }

    private void toggleColor(final EditText source, final boolean isValid) {
        int backgroundColor = (isValid) ? Color.GREEN : Color.RED;
        source.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
    }

    private void checkValidity(final EditText source, final String expected) {
        boolean valid = isValid(source, expected);
        toggleColor(source, valid);

        if (valid){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText missingText11 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.car1);
        final EditText missingText12 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.car2);
        final EditText missingText13 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.car3);

        Button buttonCheck = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCheck);

        buttonCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                checkValidity(missingText11, "maserati");
                checkValidity(missingText12, "mercedes");
                checkValidity(missingText13, "bmw");

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что `startActivity(intent);` приводит к созданию нового `SecondActivity` и переходу в него?

Comment: У вас в логике ошибка, у вас отработает `startActivity` если хоть один вариант правельный

Comment: @NickVolynkin да, совершенно верно

Comment: checkValidity у вас вызывается три раза подряд. То есть, если хоть один ответ правильный, то уже произойдет переход на новое activity. А в случае трех правильных ответов откроется три SecondActivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что в данный момент `checkValidity` управляет логикой проверки значения и отображения в одном `EditText`. Внутри себя этот метод знает про валидность только одного значения и не обладает всей информацией, чтобы принять решение, зависящее от всех полей ввода.

Тем более, этот метод вызывается трижды и запустит Intent если хотя бы в одном из полей верное значение.

Его нужно переработать так, чтобы он проверял все поля и запускался однажды. Если каждое окажется валидным, только тогда нужно будет запускать Intent. Поскольку его логика специфична именно для кнопки, то объявление метода стоит перенести в анонимный класс обработчика нажатия (переименован в `checkEditText`). Кроме того, если его оставить на месте, то появятся два похожих метода с сигнатурой `boolean(EditText, String)`, что создает почву для ошибок.

Два других метода реализуют достаточно базовую логику. которая может понадобиться и в других частях приложения. Например, вы можете проверять валидность при обновлении поля. Поэтому они остаются в теле MainActivity.

В прошлый раз я определенно ошибся с именем метода `toggleColor`. Метод просто визуализирует валидность и нам неважно, каким образом он это делает. Переименовал.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private boolean isValid(final EditText editText, final String expected) {
        String actual = editText.getText().toString();
        return expected.equals(actual);
    }

    /** Визуализирует валидность поля. Как именно - неважно */
    private void visualizeValidity(final EditText editText, final boolean isValid) {
        int backgroundColor = (isValid) ? Color.GREEN : Color.RED;
        editText.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText car1Text= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.car1);
        final EditText car2Text= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.car2);
        final EditText car3Text= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.car3);

        Button buttonCheck = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCheck);

        buttonCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            boolean checkEditText(final EditText source, final String expected) {
                boolean valid = isValid(source, expected);
                visualizeValidity(source, valid);
                return valid;
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                boolean allTextsValid = (
                    checkEditText(car1Text, R.id.expectedCar1) &
                    checkEditText(car2Text, R.id.expectedCar2) &
                    checkEditText(car3Text, R.id.expectedCar3)
                );

                if (allTextsValid) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, Nick! Блин, я вообще не туда полез.. Надо прокачивать свои знания в java..

Comment: @НиколайБойко Пожалуйста. Лишний раз порекомендую не хардкодить строковые константы, а хранить их в ресурсах.

Comment: Да, спасибо, учту!

Comment: @НиколайБойко закину еще идею. А что если полей станет не 3, а 10? А если неизвестно, сколько их будет? Что тогда делать?

Comment: вы намекаете на массив? Я думал над этим, так же над тем, а что если ещё и вариантов написания будет больше. Правда, я смутно представляю, как это реализовать..

Answer (score 0):

Перенесите вызов активити в обработчик **OnClickListener** после проверки всех условий. Пусть **checkValidity** проверяет все **TextEdit'ы** и возвращает нам результат проверок.

```
private boolean checkValidity() {
    boolean valid = true;
    //Первая проверка
    if(isValid(missingText11, "maserati")) {
        toggleColor(missingText11, true);
    } else {
        toggleColor(missingText11, false);
        valid = false;
    }
    //Вторая проверка
    if(isValid(missingText12, "mercedes")) {
        toggleColor(missingText12, true);
    } else {
        toggleColor(missingText12, false);
        valid = false;
    }
    //Третья проверка
    if(isValid(missingText13, "bmw")) {
        toggleColor(missingText13, true);
    } else {
        toggleColor(missingText13, false);
        valid = false;
    }
    //Возвращаем результат всех проверок
    return valid
    }
}
```

В обработчике пишем:

```
 buttonCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(checkValidity()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
           }
    });
```

В этом случае SecondActivity вызовится толко если все проверки вернули true.

Comment: А вот и нет. Если первая проверка вернула `false`, то следующие даже не будут выполняться (и не покрасятся нужным цветом). Так устроены логические вычисления в Java: если уже ясно, что значение будет `false`, то последующие аргументы можно не вычислять, сэкономив ресурсы. Я предполагал, что автор вопроса может сделать эту ошибку. но вы его опередили )

Comment: Это легко исправить заменив `&&` на `&`

Comment: @SorryForMyEnglish ага, можно. Но есть вторая проблема: так в коде появляются два метода с одинаковой сигнатурой, которые возвращают информацию о том, валидно ли поле. Сейчас понятно, какой из них использовать, а вот через некоторое время это может быть забыто и вместо `checkValidity` будет использован `isValid`.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ты прав, конечно же. Но смысл этого ответа был в том что вызывать активити надо после всех проверок,  а не после каждой.

Comment: @ИналТуаев про смысл согласен, ошибку исправил и минус снял ))

Comment: @ИналТуаев, это нечто похожее на первый мой вариант: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/443169/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7-edittext-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8?noredirect=1#comment467316_443169